# Trouble Integrating Search Endpoint with Flight-Radar1 API in Vite React Redux Toolkit Project

Tags: vite

I integrated flights/list-in-boundary and flights/detail endpoints into my Vite React Redux Toolkit project using the https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/flight-radar1/ API, but I'm having trouble integrating the search endpoint.

I attempted to integrate the search endpoint from the Flight-Radar1 API into my Vite React Redux Toolkit project. I reviewed the API documentation and tried different configurations for the searchOptions object. However, I encountered a 404 error, and despite checking the endpoint URL and headers, I couldn't resolve the issue. I also checked online forums and community discussions for similar problems but couldn't find a solution.